# How would I go about to get fold marks with scrartcl?

Tags: koma-script, scrartcl

Given the following MWE (I used LuaLaTeX to compile it):

```
\documentclass[version=last,paper=A4,fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{libertine-otf}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

How would I go about to activate fold marks? It it at all possible without the use extreme LaTeX-fu? I.e. by using an additional package or one of the countless KOMA-Script options?

---

Here's the effect -- with regards to the fold marks *only* -- that I desire:

```
\documentclass[version=last,paper=A4,fontsize=14pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{libertine-otf}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Weihnachtsmann\\Postfach 42\\Nordpol}
        \opening{Sehr geehrter Herr Weihnachtsmann,}
        \closing{Tschö mit \enquote{ö}}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KOMA-Script class `scrlttr2` and KOMA-Script package `scrletter` provide the foldmarks only for the first page of a letter. But you can load package `scrlayer-scrpage`, define layers containing the foldmarks. Then you can declare a new layer page style and add the foldmark layers to this style. It is also possible to add the new layers to an existing layer page style or to all layer page styles.

Example with foldmarks only on the first page and empty header and footer on this page:

```latex
\documentclass[%
  %version=last,paper=A4,% default
  fontsize=14pt,
  DIV=calc% to avoid a warning
]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{libertine-otf}% I do not have this package
\usepackage[german]{babel}% really german and not ngerman?
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setparsizes{0pt}{2ex}{0pt plus 1fil}% do not set \parskip and \parindent manually!

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcommand\foldmarklength{2mm}
\newcommand\punchmarklength{4mm}
\newcommand\markhpos{3.5mm}
\newcommand\markthickness{.2mm}
\newcommand\tfoldmarkvpos{.34\paperheight}
\newcommand\bfoldmarkvpos{.67\paperheight}

\newcommand\leftmarkline[1]{%
  \parbox[c][\layerheight][b]{\layerwidth}{%
    \hspace*{\markhpos}\rule{#1}{\markthickness}%
}}
\newif\ifFoldmark\Foldmarktrue
\newif\ifPunchmark\Punchmarktrue
\DeclareNewLayer[{
  background,
  innermargin,
  oddpage,% in twoside mode only on odd pages!
  height=\tfoldmarkvpos,
  contents={\ifFoldmark\leftmarkline{\foldmarklength}\fi}
}]{tfoldmark}
\DeclareNewLayer[{
  clone=tfoldmark,
  height=\bfoldmarkvpos
}]{bfoldmark}
\DeclareNewLayer[{
  clone=tfoldmark,
  height=.5\paperheight,
  contents={\ifPunchmark\leftmarkline{\punchmarklength}\fi}
}]{punchmark}
% add the wanted fold marks to the layer page style(s) used on subsequent pages
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{foldmarks}{tfoldmark,bfoldmark,punchmark}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{foldmarks}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Additional remark:** Do not set \parskip and \parindent manually. Maybe you can use KOMA-Script option `parskip=half-` or `parskip=full-`. If the skip between paragraphs should be `2ex` use

```latex
\setparsizes{0pt}{2ex}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

Comment: Hey @esdd, thanks so much. Yep, I want `german`, not `ngerman`. Also thanks for taking the time to remark on `\parskip` and `\parindent`. I had no idea. It's presumably a piece of conventional wisdom that has changed over time, but where I am not up-to-date. The remainder of the answer I need to process first. Thanks again!